# ssh config wildcards to avoid typing username

Tags: ssh, configuration

I frequently ssh into openstack instances. All of the instances are on a dedicated vlan and subnet (10.2.x.x). All of the instances have the same username (bob)

I connect like so:

```
ssh bob@10.2.x.x
```

or sometimes like this

```
ssh 10.2.x.x -l bob
```

**Is it possible to configure my laptop to automatically use the name bob when I ssh into any vm on the 10.2.x.x subnet?** I don't want to automatically use bob when sshing into a machine on any other subnet.

It looks like [ssh config](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) doesn't support wildcards. (Correct me if I am wrong). I'm thinking maybe an alias could do this, but I'm not sure what the syntax would be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The ssh_config man page has a section `PATTERNS` which details how you can do that, you *can* use wildcards of `*` and `?`. In my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host 172.16.*.*
   User drav
```

and then on issuing `ssh -vvv 172.16.13.1`:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/drav/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/drav/.ssh/config line 4: Applying options for 172.16.*.*
debug1: /home/drav/.ssh/config line 46: Applying options for *
```

Note that these matches are canonical, so if "fred.mynetwork.com" in DNS is 172.16.13.1, issuing `ssh fred.mynetwork.com` will not match the `Host 172.16.*.*` entry. You could always however, add an additonal `Host *.mynetwork.com` entry to apply the same options when a DNS name is used instead.

Comment: Yes, an entry `Host 10.2*` will do the trick

Comment: I found 10.2.*.* caused my key to be rejected. Changing to 10.2.* caused the connection to succeed.

Comment: Strange, for me the x.x.*.* works :/ At least there is your comment if people find issues!